Can't get PHP CS Fixer to work with custom rules in PhpStorm
I want to use PHP CS Fixer with a custom ruleset, so I have created a .php-cs-fixer.php in the document root.
In the "Settings > PHP > Quality Tools > PHP CS Fixer" I have set the option ruleset to custom and added the path to .php-cs-fixer.php. On save I get no errors, so it is reading the file correctly (or so I assume) but there is no highlighting when the rules are not met. (The others options beside custom do work such as PSR-12)
When I run the php-cs-fixer fix app in the terminal it will read the .php-cs-fixer.php and adjust files correctly.
How do I get the highlighting correctly in PhpStorm?
